# Android Notification setContentText dissapears after update

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I have a Notification that displays information about the song that is playing in my app. Everything seems to work, but when I update the Notification the setContentText disappears.

Here is my code:

```
public void buildnotification() {

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Playback.class);
notificationIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.MAIN_ACTION);
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
        notificationIntent, 0);

Intent previousIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MediaPlayerService.class);
previousIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.PREV_ACTION);
PendingIntent ppreviousIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0,
        previousIntent, 0);

Intent playIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MediaPlayerService.class);
playIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.PLAY_ACTION);
PendingIntent pplayIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0,
        playIntent, 0);

Intent nextIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MediaPlayerService.class);
nextIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION.NEXT_ACTION);
PendingIntent pnextIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0,
        nextIntent, 0);

Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
        R.mipmap.coloredlogo);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

int notifyID = 1;
NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
mNotifyBuilder.setContentTitle("Scripture Singer")
        .setTicker("Scripture Singer")
        .setContentText(dName)
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.MediaStyle())
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.logonowords)
        .setLargeIcon(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(icon, 128, 128, false))
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setOngoing(true);

mNotifyBuilder.addAction(R.mipmap.ic_skip_previous_black_48dp, "Previous", ppreviousIntent);

//changes play and pause
if (mp.isPlaying()) {
    mNotifyBuilder.addAction(R.mipmap.ic_pause_black_48dp, "Pause",
            pplayIntent);
} else {
    mNotifyBuilder.addAction(R.mipmap.ic_play_arrow_black_48dp, "Play",
            pplayIntent);
}

mNotifyBuilder.addAction(R.mipmap.ic_skip_next_black_48dp, "Next", pnextIntent);

mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID, mNotifyBuilder.build());
}
```

Do you guys have any ideas as to why this may be happening?

Comment: How are you updating the notification ? Can you paste the code ?

Comment: I just call buildnotification().

Comment: Did you checked that "dName" is changing everytime you call buildnotification() ?

Comment: It isn't changing every time I call buildnotification(). Is it supposed to?

Comment: No, You mean whatever you are setting in  .setContentText(dName) you cannot see it after you call buildnotification  for the second time, right ?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys. I was recalling a intent.getStringExtra() from an intent that would no longer have the variable. Thanks for your help though.